# How to fix Link base "img/Yellow.svg" cannot be context relative (/) or page relative

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot, thymeleaf, html-email

I am getting a 500 error when I reference `images/Yellow.svg` in my thymeleaf html email template. The error I get is the following:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   Link base "img/Yellow.svg" cannot be context relative (/) or page relative unless you implement the org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext interface (context is of class: org.thymeleaf.context.Context) (../templates/create-account-email:49)

Here is my code for referencing the image:

```
<img id="right-logo" src="../static/img/Yellow.svg" th:src="@{img/Yellow.svg}" alt="yellow logo"/>
```

I tried doing the following but it did not work for me.

````
<img id="right-liberty-logo" src="../static/img/Yellow.svg" th:src="@{~img/Yellow.svg}" alt="yellow liberty logo"/>```
````

Comment: Not to throw spanner in the works but svg doesnt have good support across email clients. [support for svg](https://css-tricks.com/a-guide-on-svg-support-in-email/)

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded thymeleaf example project ([pet clinic](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleafexamples-petclinic)) and changed *pets.png* image to svg file I added to project:

```
 src
  └───  main
      └───  webapp
          └───  resources
              └───  images
                  └─── test.svg
```

Everything worked fine. In file *welcome.html* where this image is displayed the path to the file is set like this:
`<img src="../../resources/images/test.svg" th:src="@{/resources/images/test.svg}" />`
Path of *welcome.html* is:

```
 src
  └───  main
      └───  webapp
          └───  WEB-INF
              └───  thymeleaf
                  └─── welcome.html
```

Make sure your `src` as well as `th:src` attributes are correctly set.